# Gatsby - use art direction for static images

Tags: gatsby

Is it possible to use `withArtDirection` for static images in Gatsby?

I want to generate picture tags such as the following. Static file paths will go into the src and the srcset attributes.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

In the [official document](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#withartdirection), there is an example of using `withArtDirection` for dynamic images, but there seems to be no examples for static images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the [official document](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#withartdirection), there is an example of using
> withArtDirection for dynamic images, but there seems to be no examples
> for static images.

I doesn't because `withArtDirection` is a helper function that works with `gatsbyImageData` (a node that GraphQL generates along with Gatsby for the static assets):

> **There are a number of utility functions to help you work with
> `gatsbyImageData` objects**. We strongly recommend that you do not try to
> access the internals of these objects directly, as the format could
> change.

Since you don't have `gatsbyImageData` because the asset is not locally analyzed, you can't use it.

The same applies to other helper functions such as [`getSrc`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#getsrc), [`getImage`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#getimage) or [`getSrcSet`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#getsrcset).

A similar approach could be done loading one image or the other based on the viewport width or using CSS to display one image or the other, similar to what `withArtDirection` does.